# Metallic Gradient Foil vector effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, gradient

I'm attempting to create a gradient foil effect, however I can't seem to find any direction as to how to make this as a vector. I've seen other examples like the one below, but the ones I've made look way to harsh and not modern at all. Are there any techniques I can use to replicate this effect?[image]

Comment: Gradient filled rectangles ? Look at Illustrators Metal Gradients in the Swatch Libraries and see how they were constructed ? (Swatch Libraries> Gradients> Metals)

Answer (score 1):

They appear to be basic gradient fills. Nothing overly complex.

[image]

To "color tint" the rectangles, one method would be to add an *additional fill* via the **Appearance Panel** and then lower it's opacity or change the blend mode, or both...

[image]